# Template Design Pattern in Python question on overriding the template method

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns

Am I violating the template design pattern in Python?

So I have a base class where I created the template method and I wanted to create two additional classes that I can use to do a normal function return and generator function yield?

I had to override the do_something method and change the statement from "return" to keyword "yield" or is there another alternative design code changes that I should have done?

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class BaseClass(ABC):
    def do_something(self):
        x = self.do_step1()
        y = self.do_step2()
        return x + y

    @abstractmethod
    def do_step1(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def do_step2(self):
        pass

class ReturnClass(BaseClass):
    def do_something(self):
        x = self.do_step1()
        y = self.do_step2()
        return x + y

    def do_step1(self):
        return 1

    def do_step2(self):
        return 1

class YieldClass(BaseClass):
    def do_something(self):
        x = self.do_step1()
        y = self.do_step2()
        yield x + y

    def do_step1(self):
        return 2

    def do_step2(self):
        return 2

class ConcreteReturnClass(ReturnClass):
    def do_step1(self):
        return 3

    def do_step2(self):
        return 3

class ConcreteYieldClass(YieldClass):
    def do_step1(self):
        return 4

    def do_step2(self):
        return 4

if __name__ == '__main__':
    return_class = ConcreteReturnClass();
    print(return_class.do_something())

    yield_class = ConcreteYieldClass();
    print(next(yield_class.do_something()))
```

My goal is to create a base class to serve as a template but I wanted to reuse the same class and change the implementation from returning just a single keyword to yielding just like how generator functions are.  I think I am violating the principle but I could not figure out a viable alternative.

Answer (score 1):

In class `BaseClass` `do_something` would be your *template method*, that is, it "defines an algorithm in terms of abstract operations that subclasses override to provide concrete behavior." In this case those operations are provided by abstract methods `do_step1` and `do_step2`, which need to be overriden by subclasses.

Yet in subclass `ReturnClass` you have overridden the template method `do_something` itself. Although not forbidden, it is not usual. But in this case you have provided what appears to be an implementation identical to the one in the base class, so this accomplishes nothing. I have no idea why you say you "had to override the do_something method."

```
x = ReturnBase(): print(x.do_something()) // prints 2
```

The above prints `2` regardless of whether `do_something` is overriden is `ReturnClass` or not *given you have provided an identical definition*.

At the risk of sounding pedantic:

But the real problem I see is this: A class or interface represents a contract. For each method there are implied preconditions that must be fulfilled before a call can be made. For a class that implements a `stack` and has a `pop` operation, the precondition before calling `pop` is that the stack must have at least one element in it for the operation to succeed. Likewise, there is an implied postcondition for each method call. In the last example, the promise is that the `pop` method will leave the stack with one fewer item than before the call. When a subclass overrides a base class method, it must honor the implied contract in requiring no stronger preconditions on method calls nor promise to deliver less on method returns.

In your example you have two subclasses whose `do_something` method return totally different type of results. This is fundamental violation of the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) that states that if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S. While objects of type `YieldClass` may be a *subclass* of `BaseClass`, it is not a *subtype* of `BaseClass` because method `do_something_1` in `BaseClass` (as well as in `ReturnClass`) returns an `int` whereas method `do_something_1` in `YieldClass` returns a generator. Class `YeldClass` violates its base class' contract and is very poor object-oriented design. In short, this is no longer The Template Method Pattern but is what is known as an *anti-pattern*.

Comment: Yep I think I am violating it. But I am thinking of a way of reusing the same process. The only problem is that one is like a generator function and the other is like a normal return function

Comment: You had to redefine the template method; that's not exactly "reusing the same process." You should probably re-ask the question providing much more actual detail as to what you are really trying to do and perhaps the same or a combination of patterns might solve it.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by Booboo, you are indeed breaking the base class contract here. And you are also duplicating code, which is a sure recipe for subtle bugs. As a more general answer, if you find yourself overridding the template method then you have a design issue.

In your current example (nb: I assume your real code yields more than one value - else I really don't see the point), a better solution would be to account for this need by adding the new responsability to the base class directly (under a different method name of course) and re-implement the current base `do_something()` method in terms of the new generator method ie:

```
class BaseClass(ABC):

    def iter_do_something(self):
        x = self.do_step1()
        y = self.do_step2()
        yield x + y

    def do_something(self):
        # in real life - assuming 'iter_do_something' yields more
        # than one single value - you would just return the whole list
        # instead of it's first element.
        return list(self.iter_do_something())[0]

    @abstractmethod
    def do_step1(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def do_step2(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Yes, but they do follow the same principle..only that one is yielding and the other is a normal return class... Is there an option that I can do here?

Comment: The example above has both - you just have to use either one method or the other. Having the same method returning either a value or a generator breaks Liskov's substitution principle (your `YieldClass` is not a proper subtype of `BaseClass`, you cannot substitute one for the other), and duplicating the template method logic is a DRY violation. Now if you posted an example more representative of your real use case (what's the point of yielding one single value ???) and explained why you're trying to do this you might get better answers...